# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException procedure has no parameters and arguments were supplied. How should I go about fixing this error?

Tags: sql-server

I built a database application in Visual Studio. When I run, I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: procedure sp_select_number_of_films has no parameters and arguments were supplied.

I know what the error means, but I am not sure how to fix it in my SQL code. I have tried a bunch of small tweaks, but I still get the same error.

[image: I]

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_select_number_of_films]
     (@REC_ID_OUTPUT int OUTPUT)
AS
    SELECT COUNT(*)  
    FROM Film.Title;


EXEC dbo.sp_select_number_of_films
GO
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1):

It should be called as:

```
DECLARE @sth INT;
Exec dbo.sp_select_number_of_films @sth OUTPUT;
```

But then inside stored procedure you need to assign output variable:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_select_number_of_films]( @REC_ID_OUTPUT int OUTPUT)
AS SELECT  @REC_ID_OUTPUT = COUNT(*)
FROM Film.Title;
```

And you should avoid naming stored procedures with ["sp_" prefix](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix).

Comment: I did that and It still gives me the exact same error.